# How to fetch Sql Not Null fields in php?

Tags: php, sql

how can i reject the sql table empty fields and i want to fetch that not null fields in another page

This is my query

```
SELECT     e.r_id, 
           e.cmpnyname, 
           e.st_name, 
           e.week, 
           e.desig, 
           e.cm_id, 
           e.weekly_reports 
FROM       reports AS e 
INNER JOIN company AS u 
ON         u.cmpnyname = e.cmpnyname 
WHERE      e.weekly_reports IS NOT NULL 
AND        e.cm_id = ".$_GET['id'];
```

But this query fetches all the fields including null fields

Can anyone help me to find this

Comment: What's wrong with your current code?

Comment: `reject the sql table empty fields` specify the column which you beleive will be NULL. And sanitize user input `$_GET['id']` before actually using it into the query, your code is vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: i dont know but e.weekly_reports i want to fetch this not null columns but this query fetches all the empty fields

Comment: Can you help me to sanitize the $_GET['id'] this field

Comment: try `e.weekly_reports IS NOT NULL and e.weekly_reports != ''`.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php

Comment: woww tats working thank you so much @Jigar

Comment: Sorry couldnt understand you @JYoThI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select both Empty and NULL values

```
SELECT e.r_id,
       e.cmpnyname,
       e.st_name,
       e.week,
       e.desig,
       e.cm_id,
       e.weekly_reports
FROM reports AS e
INNER JOIN company AS u ON u.cmpnyname = e.cmpnyname
WHERE NULLIF(e.weekly_reports, ' ') IS NOT NULL
  AND e.cm_id =".$_GET['id']."
```

another statement is much cleaner and more readable

```
WHERE ISNULL(NULLIF(e.weekly_reports, ''));
```